Extra large brackets with greek letters in Mathematica 14
In expressions with Greek letters, the spacing and bracket sizes are very large compared to normal Latin letters.
Consider for example
wtc = {u -> (a[#1, #2]/\[Psi][#1, #2]^(1 + I \[Delta]) &), 
   v -> (b[#1, #2]/\[Psi][#1, #2]^(1 - I \[Delta]) &)};
wtc = {u -> (a[#1, #2]/d[#1, #2]^(1 + I x) &), 
   v -> (b[#1, #2]/d[#1, #2]^(1 - I x) &)};

which looks like this


Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. First, please don't use [bugs] tags for new questions, it is meant only for confirmed bugs. Second, if I retype your equations, I get normally sized parenthesis. Can you please let us know how you got to your form? And also which OS you are using.

My version is "14.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)", I am on Arch linux. I just type them and the moment I enter a greek character, the bracket becomes bigger.

I also tried after resetting all preferences to defaults.

It might be due to your operating system ... Can you make a more simple example, then select the cell, go to menu Cell > Show Expression, and paste the code?

Cell[BoxData[  RowBox[{"(", "\[Psi]", ")"}]], "Input",  CellChangeTimes->{{3.934266942566764*^9, 3.93426694534973*^9}}] for (:psi:)

What you posted should render like this. And now I finally remembered that there was already an issue about this posted this year: Weirdly big spacing around ε character, using Arch Linux! It has no answers yet. You probably should write to Wolfram Technical Support.

Looks like there was some issue with the fonts. I sorted it by installing ttf-dejavu.
